# Python-requests module, post two "values" to renew&scrape website

Tags: javascript, python, http, python-requests

The first part was already answered, however, EDIT isn't.

I am using python and the requests module to scrape a website. Therefore I have to “click” a Renew-Button, which is a link(href) wrapped in an image “pat_renewmark.gif”.

**html**

```
<form name="checkout_form" method="POST" id="checkout_form">
    <input type="HIDDEN" id="checkoutpagecmd">
    <a href="#" onclick="return submitCheckout( 'sortByCheckoutDate', 'bycheckoutdate' )"> 
        <img src="/screens/pat_sortbychkout.gif" alt="SORT BY DATE CHECKED OUT" border="0">
    </a>
    <input type="HIDDEN" name="currentsortorder" value="current_duedate">
    <a href="#" onclick="return submitCheckout( 'requestRenewSome', 'requestRenewSome' )">
        <img src="/screens/pat_renewmark.gif" alt="RENEW SELECTED ITEMS" border="0">
    </a>
</form>
```

**javascript** *(submitCheckout)*

```
function submitCheckout(buttonname, buttonvalue)
{
    var oHiddenID;
    oHiddenID = document.getElementById("checkoutpagecmd");

    oHiddenID.name = buttonname;
    oHiddenID.value = buttonvalue;

    //c29364j/c1365070 - prevent the patron from submitting twice
    var oButtonSpan;
    oButtonSpan = document.getElementById("checkoutbuttons0");
    if (oButtonSpan) oButtonSpan.style.display = "none";
    oButtonSpan = document.getElementById("checkoutbuttons1");
    if (oButtonSpan) oButtonSpan.style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("checkout_form").submit();
    return true;
}
```

Apparently *submitCheckout*  passes `.name` and `value`, which are both assigned to `”requestRenewSome”’, to the hidden input with the`id=“checkoutpagecmd”`.

---

I’ve worked with the requests module before and I am able to handle a simple username&password input , for example:

**html**

```
<div class="formEntryArea">
    <label for="extpatid">
         <span class="formLabel">
        Your username:
        </span>
    </label>
    <input name="extpatid" id="extpatid" value="" size="20" maxlength="40">
    <label for="extpatpw">
        <span class="formLabel">
        Your password:
        </span>
    </label>
    <input name="extpatpw" id="extpatpw" type="PASSWORD" value="" size="20" maxlength="40">
</div>
```

**python**

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:

        LOGIN_URL = "https://example.com"
        USERNAME = “XXXXX”
        PASSWORD = “YYYYY”

        source = c.get(LOGIN_URL)

        data_load = dict(extpatid=USERNAME,extpatpw=PASSWORD)
        head_load = dict(referer=LOGIN_URL)

        c.post(LOGIN_URL, data=data_load, headers=head_load)
```

However, here c.post is handling only one “value” per input (either USERNAME or PASSWORD) and no javascript code is included.
As it seems, for the problem above I somehow have to post the two attributes/strings
.name = 'requestRenewSome'
.value = 'requestRenewSome'
? Or is the approach completely different to the example I attached?

---

## EDIT

The answer from matino (or the comment from t.m.adam) solves the problem! Unfortunately the User then has to approve that he is sure he wants to renew by clicking a YES button.

**html**

```
<form name="checkout_form" method="POST" id="checkout_form">
    <input type="HIDDEN" id="checkoutpagecmd">
    <input type="HIDDEN" name="currentsortorder" value="current_duedate">
    <span id="checkoutbuttons0">
        <input type="SUBMIT" name="renewsome" value="YES">
        <input type="SUBMIT" name="donothing" value="NO">
    </span>
</form>
```

I therefore added `'renewsome': 'YES'`to the `data_load` dictionary, but thats not enough. I don't know the value for the hidden input/s? `id=checkoutpagecmd` and/or? `name=currentsortorder` but couldn't find any answer on how to proceed.

P.S. I know it's actually a knew question, and I'm going to separate it, if it's getting answered.

Comment: So `data = {'requestRenewSome':'requestRenewSome'}`?

Comment: Thank you @t.m.adam , that's solving it! Unfortunately another problem occurred, which I added in the EDIT part.

Comment: Without the actual url it's hard to tell if it's possible with `requests`. Why don't you inspect the network traffic to see what data get submitted when you click the button?

Comment: thanks for the help, however the answer was trivial haha, an empty string ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the javascript code actually does is dynamically assigning name and value to the hidden input. So in the end there can be 2 cases:

```
<input type="hidden" id="checkoutpagecmd" name="sortByCheckoutDate" value= "bycheckoutdate">
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" id="checkoutpagecmd" name="requestRenewSome" value= "requestRenewSome">
```

Knowing that, you can send http request like this:

```
requests.post(url, data={'sortByCheckoutDate': 'bycheckoutdate'})  # 1st case
requests.post(url, data={'requestRenewSome': 'requestRenewSome'})  # 2nd case
```